# Nginx -s quit does nothing after 1.8 upgrade, how can I debug and/or find the issue?

Tags: nginx

The premise of this question is unfortunately vague but I can't pinpoint a more specific issue. I upgraded a machine from nginx 1.6.3 to 1.8 and now issuing a `nginx -s quit` does literally nothing. The command gives no output, the access_log and error_log files show nothing abnormal, even with the [debug level](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) enabled in all vhosts. There is also nothing in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` other than "signal process started" notices. `pgrep nginx` show that the processes stay there like nothing happened.

I understand that the quit signal doesn't necessarily stop nginx immediately since it's supposed to quit *gracefully*, but the issue here is that even if the machine is firewalled, isolated, and processing no requests, `nginx -s quit` still does nothing. Under the exact same conditions with 1.6.3 the processes stop immediately.

I'm at a complete loss at how debug this issue and find the root cause but obviously something is amiss. Any help to point me into the right direction would be much appreciated.

Edit: The behaviour we are seeing is the following, step by step:

1. apt-get update/upgrade a machine with nginx 1.6.3 to 1.8 (when prompted install the new /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
2. `sudo nginx -s quit` for the first time works as expected
3. `sudo service nginx start` brings nginx back as expected
4. `sudo nginx -s quit` for the second time does nothing any longer, and will stay as such even after rebooting

We tested this multiple times in a VM and the results are consistent. Perhaps it's a bug in 1.8?

Comment: What happens if you send the relevant signal to the nginx process manually (i.e. kill -QUIT)?  If that works, contents of pid file could be simply wrong (i.e. point to nonexistent process) for some reason.

Comment: @sendmoreinfo will check that, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason that we haven't located yet, on our environment nginx creates two pid files: `/run/nginx.pid` and `/var/run/nginx.pid`. This appears to happen regardless the nginx version so it seems it's not a nginx bug per se.

Running `nginx -s quit` does not kill and delete the pids as it should, but `service nginx stop` does. So in order to do a graceful restart in an up-to-date nginx version we have to run both:

1. `sudo nginx -s quit`
2. `sudo service nginx stop` (after a minute or so to give time for the graceful quit)
3. `sudo service nginx start`

Subsequent `quit` signals will work fine then, as long as nginx is stopped via the service command to ensure the pids don't lag around.